# Flutter convert package or dart:convert

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I am following a Flutter [tutorial](https://youtu.be/sisZllMjoX0). 
JSON is converted using the dart convert library: `import 'dart:convert';`
However, I see that a flutter package is available which would also work, using: `import 'package:convert/convert.dart';` and adding `convert: ^2.1.1` as a dependency in the app pubspec.yaml file.

The convert package readme states "This package contains encoders and decoders for converting between different data representations. It's the external counterpart of the dart:convert core library, and *contains less-central APIs and APIs that need more flexible versioning*."

What does "*contains less-central APIs and APIs that need more flexible versioning*" mean?
Which method is preferable / best practice and why? Are there performance differences between using the dart:convert core library and the Flutter package?

Comment: It's typical to use both (as required). For example `dart:convert` provides the UTF-8 and JSON codecs, whereas `package:convert` provides other codecs like a hexadecimal encoder/decoder.  The comment is just telling you that the hex codec is a lot less popular than the other examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`'dart:convert'` contains the conversion utility that's built-in to the Dart framework. `package:convert` on the other hand is the external counterpart. Depending on the API that you need to use, you can use either of the two as needed. If the converter that you need is present on one, you can use that library, and same the other way around.